# Getting Google Oauth2 Token using dotnetopenauth

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm having an issue retreiving the OAuth2 token for google using DotNetOpenAuth 4.2.0.13024.

I've got to the point where I can successfully make the authorization request to the google endpoint https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

When the user clicks 'OK', google then calls my callback URL as expected with the appropriate "code" query string.

However, I am unable to exchange this code for a token, as my calls keep failing with "Protocol exception was unhandled" execption and "400 Bad request" as the inner exception. This is the code I am using to exchange the token

```
private static AuthorizationServerDescription authServerDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription
{
    TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
    AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
};

static GoogleContacts()
{
    Client = new WebServerClient(authServerDescription, "{my_cliend_id}", "{me_secret_key}");
}

var authorization = Client.ProcessUserAuthorization(); // <- Exception is thrown here
if (authorization != null)
{
   Authorization = authorization;
   Response.Redirect(Request.Path); // get rid of the /?code= parameter
}
```

PS: it seems like a new version of DotNerOpenAuth has been released but, I am unable to get it because the zip download still points to the older version and Nuget keeps failing on me :(

Comment: Can you please add [logs](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs) to your question?

Comment: @Andrew Installed Glimpse, here's what happened:
It replaced the current version of DotNetOpenAuth with version 3.4 - I cant use this version of the DLL because I need to test for OAuth2. So anyways, I replaced the DLL with version 4.2. I configured Glimpse, and got the panel to open, however, the DotNetOpenAuth tab is disabled.

I then tried log4net approach with the configuration setting as described in the link above - all I got was an empty Relyingparty.log file

If its any help, I've put the entire code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iZGwBqqV). Hope thats of any help

Comment: I've never used the glimpse approach myself. I always just use log4net to append to a log file as your second attempt was. Where did you acquire log4net for your web app? You should probably ensure that you're using log4net v1.2.11 exactly (nothing older or newer). That may help.

Comment: @Andrew: I've [uploaded the logs to ZeroBin](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?c600ade0298d3eb2#Z5aotL+UoVfJX9Rbh0rFgmdtV6Og2xXTKD0EtYiL6Q4=)

If its any help, the [full code is also uploaded on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iZGwBqqV)

Comment: @AndrewArnott Do you see anything unusual in the logs or my code?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Maybe double check your client_id and secret are right, and that they are being sent in the HTTP Authorization header of the final outgoing request (the one that is currently failing).

Comment: @Andrew I double checked. Also, I think if the client_id or secret are wrong, the initial authorization call should have failed? Any chance the Google contacts sample be upgraded to OAuth2  - the current sample still uses the older protocol even though its in the OAuth2 folder. Thanks much.

Comment: The initial redirect call doesn't include the client secret, so no, that wouldn't fail if it were wrong. Updating the sample is a good idea, but it's competing with several other priorities. Feel free to [file a ticket](http://bit.ly/dnoawish) so it doesn't slip through the cracks.

Comment: Not sure if you are doing the same thing with DNOA as I am or not, but would [this code](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2) help you?